# Upload file via AJAX using laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, file-upload, bootstrap-modal

So basically I have a bootstrap modal pop up in which I want to upload a csv via jquery/ajax so I can parse through using PHP.

I'm using laravel and this is currently my code:

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="uploadRecipientListModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-center">Add Recipient List</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modal_form_id"  method="POST" >
                    <input type="file" name="documents">
                 </form>

                 <button id="uploadRecipientSubmit1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#uploadRecipientSubmit1" ).click(function() {
    var postData = new FormData($("#modal_form_id")[0]);

    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'recipient/upload-contact-list',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data : postData,
            success:function(data){
              console.log("File Uploaded" + data);
            },
            error:function(data){
              console.log("nope");
            }

        });       


});
```

Controller PHP:

```
public function uploadContactList(Request $request)
{
    if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::hasFile('documents')) {

       echo "Good";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "bad";
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/recipient/upload-contact-list', 'RecipientController@uploadContactList')->name('upload.contact.list');
```

Output in console:

```
File Uploadedbad
```

I just cant get access to the csv file i'm trying to upload so I can parse through it and upload the rows to the db.

I've been struggling on this one for a while and tried multiple different things but cant get this working, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try echoing $request->all(), what does it show?

Comment: Gives me a 500 error, weirdly

Comment: What message from the error?

Comment: I'll try my best to help as im on my phone

Comment: The exact return in the console is "File Uploaded[]bad". I added "echo json_encode($request->all());" to the start of the uploadContactList method

Comment: added that mean its no longer returning a 500 by the way

Comment: You are treating this form like a regular form without file inputs. You can't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Can anyone give an example of how to get this working then? I appreciate the links but I've gone through so  many Stack questions and documentation I must be missing something.

Comment: In ajax function, add property cache: false

Comment: Can you post request info from the network tab in your inspector?